# __new__ override does not work

Tags: python, oop, python-2.7

May I know why `myClass1` and `myClass2` behaves differently in overriding the `__new__()` method? Which way is recommended to write a class and why?  I think `myClass1():` does not even call `__new__(cls)`, am I right?

```
$ python
Python 2.7.5+ (default, Sep 19 2013, 13:49:51) 
[GCC 4.8.1] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> class myClass1():
...     def __new__(cls):
...             print cls.__name__
... 
>>> class myClass2(object):
...     def __new__(cls):
...             print cls.__name__
... 
>>> o1 = myClass1()
>>> o2 = myClass2()
myClass2
>>>
```

Answer (score 5):

When you inherit from `object` you are creating a [new-style class](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#new-style-and-classic-classes). Not inheriting from `object` makes it an old-style class.

Old-style classes don't support the `__new__` constructor.

In Python 3, *all* classes are new-style and the `object` base class is implicit if there are no explicit base classes specified.